# Google Map version2 vs Version3. shall we continue with gmap version 2

Tags: google-maps

1. My map project needed an update this month and when i referred gmap i saw the notification requesting to migrate to version3. This is from may 19th 2010.
2. There are three projects live which used gmap extensively.
3. Those projects are for Transportation department in which we have plotted a route for a bus service with many options.
4. **What will be the problem if i let the existing projects be as they were. that is in version 2.**

   I would like to have suggestions for the above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Google Deprecation Policy:

> "For a period of 3 years after an announcement (the “Deprecation Period”), Google will use commercially reasonable efforts to continue to operate the Deprecated Version of the Service and to respond to problems with the Deprecated Version of the Service deemed by Google in its discretion to be critical. During the Deprecation Period, no new features will be added to the Deprecated Version of the Service."

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_4_4

So you are probably good to keep using it for awhile - but eventually you will need to update.

Note that V3 is not guaranteed to be compliant with IE6, which is the reason why I am temporarily holding off on updating my own applications.

Comment: Last time I checked v3 was still missing some features found in v2.

Comment: What features? It has several features not found in v2.

Comment: So, in less than three years IE6 will mostly be out of the box. and we shall wait untill that or 3 years or effective workaround.
I am waiting form some more time to see for more responses for this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If v3 has all the features you need, then go with v3.

Comment: i wasn't informed myself that v3 already exists. i need to check the advt of v3. besides somebody stated that v3 has not considered IE6.